# Build a canvas or div as grid system? Takes user input and a layout for a "page"

Tags: css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I don't know really how I should tackle my problem. I would like to have a div or canvas don't know which one goes better but this will be the play ground for the user.

The user will then drag and drop some components. Prob some DIVS. The "grid" will take the divs and place them as the user wants. And then after the user have chosen couple of divs I will have a save button to saves the grid. The grid will then represent a user "page-layout". The "page-layout" is gonna be build up as the users wanted it with the placement of the divs and so on.

So is there any idea of how to solve my problem? I have searched a lot but can't find any really straight forward idea.

Comment: I'd suggest searching further. I say that because your build-with-drag-drop concept is an extremely common concept. You'll surely find what you need with some perseverance. Good luck!

Comment: Prob Mark, i hope so. If u see anyhing like this u know where to post suggastion :)